# 5 vowels and 10 consonants given, word of 6 different letters are formed and “i” is always to be one of the vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A set of alphabet consists of 5 vowels and 10 consonants. Words of 6 different letters are formed and ‘i’ is always to be one of the vowels. How many words can be formed in which
> (a)every word is to contain at least one vowel.
> (b)the words begin and end with consonants.

In this problem, me and many people had a huge disagreement as others deduce the question that “i” will always be included while I thought that “i” will be included only when there is at least a vowel included. So, there were significant differences in our answers, so I would be highly appreciated if I can have some explanation and answers to this question.

Edit*- So, yea, I will provide answers according to my reasoning here.
(a) 15C6 - 10C6 (total possibilities minus all consonants) (b) 10P2 * 13P4 <First and last chosen from 10 consonants multiply the rest in four places>

Comment: It is not stated that a word should have a vowel, so it seems like you are correct.

Comment: I assume you can see how a dishonest person could use a post like this to fish for an answer so to appease the cynics among us, could you please provide your work and your answers?

Answer (score 1):

The wording is ambiguous enough for me to not pronounce any definitive judgment of its intent, but assuming that your interpretation is correct, the answer to $(a)$ is not.
Firstly, you need permutations, not combinations, and it should be $(_{15}P_6 - \;_{14}P_6) -\; _{10}P_6$
because $i$ must be included if vowel(s) are included